# How to move BasemapGallery position in ReactJS Leaflet?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, leaflet, react-leaflet

I want to move the position in the Basemap Gallery Leaflet to the top near the Leaflet zoom on the Map but am confused about how to move the coding, here it is:

1. Basemap Gallery Brochure wants to move up and near Zoom.

Sample image: [Images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mQD97.png)

Example of desired Basemap Gallery position:
[Example of Basemap Gallery position](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MSvvm.jpg)

Here is my code and what I need to change in my code:

```
import { React, useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import {
  LayersControl,
  MapContainer,
  TileLayer,
  Marker,
  Popup,
  useMapEvents,
} from 'react-leaflet'
import List from '../Component/List'
import L from 'leaflet'
import SearchControl from './SearchControl'

const { BaseLayer } = LayersControl

function LocationMarker() {
  const [position, setPosition] = useState(null)
  const map = useMapEvents({
    locationfound(e) {
      setPosition(e.latlng)
      map.flyTo(e.latlng, map.getZoom())
    },
  })

  return position === null ? null : (
    <Marker position={position}>
      <Popup>Location Me</Popup>
    </Marker>
  )
}

function MyLocationMe() {
  const [map, setMap] = useState(null)
  const [position, setPosition] = useState(null)

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!map) return

    L.easyButton('fa-map-marker', () => {
      map.locate().on('locationfound', function (e) {
        setPosition(e.latlng)
        map.flyTo(e.latlng, map.getZoom())
      })
    }).addTo(map)
  }, [map])

  return (
    <div className="flex ml-auto">
      <List />
      <div className="w-4/5">
        <MapContainer
          center={{ lat: 51.505, lng: -0.09 }}
          zoom={20}
          style={{ height: '100vh' }}
          whenCreated={setMap}
        >
          <SearchControl className="MarkerIcon" position="topright" />
          <LayersControl position="topleft">
            <BaseLayer checked name="OpenStreetMap">
              <TileLayer
                attribution='&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
                url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png "
              />
            </BaseLayer>
          </LayersControl>
          <LocationMarker />
        </MapContainer>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
export default MyLocationMe
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to do that is to change the left css property of the relevant css class by making position absolute

Add this to your styles.css

```
.leaflet-control-layers.leaflet-control {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50px;
}
```

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-leaflet-v-3-x-how-to-move-layerscontrol-position-in-reactjs-leaflet-kw5y1f?file=/src/Map.jsx)